# how to Disable window close button and image in winui3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

[image]

I want remove window top image and close button at the same time I want app title drag and drop.

Comment: Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=wasdk but some customizations are only available for Windows 11

Comment: You could try handling WM_CLOSE messages so that Alt-F4 is also covered.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JPZaEHZj9VG4-pfANvTXm7tMxebvxJTg/view
Please see this video. Normally didn't show the minimize, maximize , close button. when mouse over those button are visible. I Want those button are disable , but must be drag and drop is needed

Comment: @Siva I have edited my reply and you could check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the native `SetWindowLong` API to do this:

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
        IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar` and `SetTitleBar` to customize the title bar.

```
 ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;
     SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);
```

When you use a custom title bar, you can modify the colors of the caption buttons to match your app.

You could add the follow code to override the default values in App.xaml:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowCaptionBackground">white</SolidColorBrush>
        
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowCaptionForeground">white</SolidColorBrush>
        

     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowCaptionButtonBackground" Color="white " Opacity="0.3"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowCaptionButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="red" Opacity="0.8"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CloseButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Magenta" Opacity="0.8"/>
```

When the mouse is not hovering:
[image]

When the mouse is hovering:
[image]

Comment: I want Title Bar. but  title bar all content disable including mouse over. At the same time i want drag and drop